# JPA: Override Auto generated ID for composite key?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Adding this question for documentation purpose, and to check if there is any alternative solution.

I have an entity which has a composite key defined using `@IdClass`

```
data class TemplateId(var id: Long? = null, var version: Int = 0) : Serializable

@Entity
@IdClass(TemplateId::class)
data class Template(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Id
    @Column(name = "version")
    var version: Int

    //Other columns
)
```

Idea is to have same ID for different versions of the `Template`. Using Sequence generator works as expected while inserting new template.
But when I try to insert a new version row with same ID, `@GeneratedValue` overrides the given value and autoincrements to new value.
Solution mentioned in [JPA: Override Auto generated ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11773358/977919)
does not work.

Comment: Just a small suggestion: why not use Envers? AFAIK such a scenario (entities having multiple revisions per id) is supported out of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out following options and none worked.

- As mentioned in the question, cannot use `@GeneratedValue` as it replaces the given value
- Cannot replace `@SequenceGenerator` with custom generator ([`@GenericGenerator`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11773358/977919)), doesn't work with composite key. It tries to cast Long value to IdClass `TemplateId`
- I am using Postgres, so tried using column type `SERIAL` for `id`. This does not work with IDENTITY GenerationType on composite key. There is an existing issue : [HHH-9662](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9662)
- Cannot use DB auto-increment with NULL value, postgres gives constraint violation error
- `"insertable"=false/ "updatable"=false` on `id` column does not work for `@Id` columns
- Similarly tried using hibernate's `@DynamicInsert` so that it will skip null column values in insert query, but even that doesn't work with `@Id`

Finally had to override the `save` function of Spring's `JpaRepository` to make it work

```
interface CustomTemplateRepository<S> {
    fun <E: S> save(entity: E): E
    fun <E: S> saveAndFlush(entity: E): E
}


class TemplateRepositoryImpl(
    private val jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate,
    @PersistenceContext private val entityManager: EntityManager
) : CustomTemplateRepository<Template> {
    override fun <E : Template> save(entity: E): E {
        if(entity.id == null)
            entity.id = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select nextval('sequence_generator')", 
                              mutableMapOf<String, Any>(), Long::class.java)
        entityManager.persist(entity)
        return entity
    }

    override fun <E : Template> saveAndFlush(entity: E): E {
        return save(entity).also {
            entityManager.flush()
        }
    }
}
```