# Spring Data Neo4j: Generate an ID only if annotated field is null on persisting new objects

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

In Spring Data Neo4j I've discovered that fields annotated with `@ID`, require an ID to be manually set. However, if the field is also annotated with `@GeneratedValue` it will use the ID generated by the database. This annoyingly overwrites any values manually being set.

I need the best of both world options. I don't particularly want to have to manually generate an ID every time within my application, and just rely on Neo4J to do it, but there are certainly times where I will want to manually set the ID (e.g. in my particular case exporting/importing system data and keep relationships working).

I expect I can set some sort of generator; however, I've been unable to get that to work.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667929/jpa-override-auto-generated-id